# "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the..." with FB.getLoginStatus

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Here, https://developers.facebook.com/apps/myappid/summary?ref=nav , i have mention "example.networks.com" in "App Domains" , and "Website with Facebook Login" - Site URL: is "http://example.networks.com"(and also i tried with http://example.networks.com/facebookEX4.htm) .
And my html page in which I am calling FB.getLoginStatus is placed at http://example.networks.com/facebookEX4.htm. But still I am gettting same error. Could you tell me what i am missing still ?

Comment: and sandbox mode = disabled.

Comment: try adding a slash at the end , something like this http://example.networks.com/facebookEX4.htm/ on your Site URL app details

Comment: yes I added but not wokring , still same error.

Comment: Yes now I am not getting Url missmatch error but getting other error as bellow."Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later.
ping?c...dk=joey (line 1)" . What could be issue ?